# How to execute multiple queries as bash script

Tags: shell, psql

I am writing one bash shell script to create connection with postgres and execute multiple queries on one connection. For that I wrote following piece of code.

```
#!/bin/sh

psql postgresql://$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@$HOST:$PORT -c << EOF
CREATE DATABASE $DB_NAME ;
create user $USER with encrypted password '$PASSWORD';
grant all privileges on database $DB_NAME to $USER;

EOF
```

But its not working and giving me following error. what's wrong with this syntax.

[image]

Comment: I guess remove `-c`. Also I suspect your file has dos line endings - remove/convert them.

Comment: yes , you were correct after removing -c its works fine. one more thing if I wan to store result of this query then how can do that.

Comment: I want to see executed if its works well other failed if does not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

psql postgresql://$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@$HOST:$PORT << EOF
CREATE DATABASE $DB_NAME ;
create user $USER with encrypted password '$PASSWORD';
grant all privileges on database $DB_NAME to $USER;

EOF
```